There are 6 identical squares in the diagram below, What is the sum of their areas?

This image shows the diagram, Now how can we prove that the left-most square's vertex connected to the right-most square's vertex is parallel to the 13 unit line?
So if we can prove that then we just get
$$(3a)^2+(2a)^2 = 13^2$$
and we solve for a which is side length of the squares.

$(3a)^2+a^2=11$, off you go :-)

@Dominique but that doesn't give correct answer?!

@Arian_Commandy: really? You subtract your equation from mine, and you end up with $3a^2=48$, leading to quite a reasonable result, isn't it?

with my equation we get the answer square root(13) for the sidelength of the square and that is the answer but the real question is how can we prove that the line actually equals 13 so that $$(3a)^2+(2a)^2 = 13^2$$

When you start with $(3a)^2+(2a)^2=13^2$, you consider that the row joining the 2 extreme points (on the right and on the left) is  horizontal, so the length would be $13$. This row is not exactly horizontal.  This does not gives the answer to the question, but it explains why your answer is wrong.

I wonder if there's some trick solution where you can take 5 extra squares, cut them up, and rearrange them with translations and rotations to cover the rectangle exactly.  Then you would get directly that $11A = 11\cdot 13$ where $A$ is the area of one of the squares, and the final answer would be $6A$.

@DanielSchepler I actually posted my answer before seeing your comment.

Deleted my answer based on that idea: it assumes the same hypothesis and doesn't really justify it.

Firstly you can draw a vertical line through the second-rightmost vertex of the little squares, like this:

Clearly the left part is a square due to the symmetry of the cross of 5 yellow squares that lies inside it and touches all four sides. Therefore the width of the cut off rectangle is 2.
Next you can cut off another width 2 rectangle, and this cut will go through the vertex at the bottom right. If you want to you can prove this rigorously using congruent right triangles, but it is pretty obvious.

Lastly, the remaining width 9 area can be split into thirds, and these cuts will again go through vertices because this area is spanned by three equal edges at an angle.

You can now see that the edges of the little squares all span 3 in one direction and 2 in the other (either 3 right and 2 down, or 2 right and 3 up). It then follows that the edges are $\sqrt{3^2+2^2}=\sqrt{13}$ in length.

While no more needed, this shows that the OP's conjecture about the leftmost and rightmost vertex is true: From the left, you go three times down by $2$, then two times up by $3$.

To elaborate on Yves Daoust's and Jaap Scherphuis's answers, if it's not clear:

Let these two perpendicular sides of the squares be vectors $(u,-v)$ and $(v,u)$.
Even if we don't know that the segment connecting the leftmost and rightmost vertices is parallel to the 13-line (that would mean $-3v + 2u = 0$), we know for sure that the horizontal distance covered is $13$, that is $3u + 2v = 13$. Similarly we know the vertical distance covered from bottom to top is $v + 3u = 11$.
We conclude $v = 2$ and $u = 3$. The side length of each square is $\sqrt{2^3 + 3^2} = \sqrt{13}$ and the total area is $6 \times \sqrt{13}^2 = 78$.
Actually there may be a similar solution rotating our view to be in the squares' coordinate frame, but it's not as obvious to me.

With a rotated view we could say with $\hat u = (\cos \theta, -\sin \theta), \hat v = (\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$ as the unit vectors parallel to the rectangle, $(3a,2a) \cdot \hat u = 13$ and $(-a,3a) \cdot \hat v = 11$. Not as nice.
